# Interface not compatible when method signature are identical

Tags: php

Here is the problem:

```
interface iSuperAdmin
{
    public function getCount();
}


class SuperAdmin implements iSuperAdmin
{
    public function getCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


interface iRegularAdmin
{
    public function getCount($count);
}


class RegularAdmin extends SuperAdmin implements iRegularAdmin
{
    public function getCount($count)
    {
        //more code here
        return $count;
    }
}


$regular = new RegularAdmin();

print $regular->getCount(3);
```

Here is the error:

`FATAL ERROR Declaration of RegularAdmin::getCount() must be compatible with that of iSuperAdmin::getCount() on line number ..`

Why php throw such error?

Class `RegularAdmin` does not implement `iSuperAdmin`, it simply inherit from `SuperAdmin`

For all i know class `RegularAdmin` overwrite `getCount` from the `SuperAdmin` class, thus correctly implement the `iRegularAdmin` interface

Is interface inheritable through class inheritance?
Any explanation is greatly appreciated

**Updated**

If i commented out `getCount` on the `RegularAdmin`,

```
  .
  .
  .

class RegularAdmin extends SuperAdmin implements iRegularAdmin
{
    /*
    public function getCount($count)
    {   //more code
        return $count;
    }*/
}


$regular = new RegularAdmin();

print $regular->getCount(3);
```

php will throw this error instead:

`FATAL ERROR Declaration of SuperAdmin::getCount() must be compatible with that of iRegularAdmin::getCount() on line number ..`

Did `class RegularAdmin extends SuperAdmin implements iRegularAdmin` declaration, make `SuperAdmin::getCount()` implement `iRegularAdmin` interface and ignore `iSuperAdmin` interface?

This is really weird

Comment: You're get count method reminds me of `function RandomNumber(){ return 4; }`

Comment: Are you trying to implement some-type of overrides? as how do you expect $regular->getCount(3) to reach the embedded functions of the same name?

Comment: @DarylGill yes i try to implement some type of overrides..this example quite silly, but it demonstrate the problem im facing off

Comment: Sorry for the delay, overriding functions are not currently possible in PHP, implementing user defined overrides on the other hand is possible, just requires a semi-complex structure. Let me see if I can find an example I posted previously. It'll give you a very rough idea on how to implement overrides

Comment: overriding is one thing, see the updated section..its really weird behaviour

Comment: On topic of your original post though, the error message is specific to the problem. You must implement the same function name and accepted parameters. In other classes whilst using implement the functions must be the same. PHP is a very faulty programming language, it's just one of those things which I'll label personally as PHP  exclusive. I'm not on a computer at the moment. When I return home I'll have a sit down with you in a chat to go over all points and figure out why specifically it's being fired. Even know it's expected behavior

Comment: Though @jacks  answer is pretty spot on in explaining this

Answer (score 2):

The interface of `iSuperAdmin` applies to whatever extends a class that implements it. And because PHP doesn't support function overloading, having these two function signatures will conflict:

```
getCount()       // from: SuperAdmin <- iSuperAdmin
getCount($count) // from: iRegularAdmin
```

If you implement `RegularAdmin::getCount` according to the second signature, it will conflict with the `iSuperAdmin` interface, as mentioned above; however, if you don't choose to implement the method, it will conflict with `iRegularAdmin` because `SuperAdmin::getCount` is implicitly chosen.

In diagram style:

```
iSuperAdmin [getCount()]
     |
 SuperAdmin      iRegularAdmin [getCount($count)]
     |                |
     +-------+--------+
             |
         RegularAdmin
```

Comment: when i implement RegularAdmin::getCount, it will conflict with iSuperAdmin cause php dont support method overloading right..What confuse me is, the `error` that php throw..here is the error `Fatal error: Declaration of RegularAdmin::getCount() must be compatible with iSuperAdmin::getCount() `..how about throw something like `duhh, u have duplicated method name`.

Comment: @slier That's because in this case the engine enforces signatures based on inheritance or interfaces; if you were to put the same method name inside a single class definition you will see a different error.

Answer (score 1):

Class `RegularAdmin` implements `iSuperAdmin` implicitly while it is inherited from class that implements `iSuperAdmin`.

Comment: Yes. Check out `var_dump($regular instanceof iSuperAdmin);` (remove conflicted method before). May be it's not mentioned in docs because it's an obvious thing.

Comment: actually its not obvious at all, if it being inherit implicitly, what happen to explicit implementation `implements iRegularAdmin` ?

Comment: Class can implement any count of interfaces. So `RegularAdmin` implements both `iSuperAdmin` and `iRegularAdmin`.

Comment: hmm, doc never mention interface can be inherit through parent class.interesting

Comment: BTW, you have 2 variants to solve your issue: `getCount($count = null);` in `iSuperAdmin` or `getRegularCount($count)` in `iRegularAdmin`. PHP doesn't support function overloading at all, and as you can see there is no way to change function signature (overwrite) in subclasses it it was defined in interface.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation says

> Note:
>
> The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method
>   signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result
>   in a fatal error.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: the class implemented same method signature, did u read the code? the child class implemented the wrong interface

Comment: same? really?  getCount() and getCount($count) ?

Comment: why it being check over iSuperAdmin interface and not iRegularAdmin interface? can u explain why?

Comment: hmmm, it checks over both interfaces - iSuperAdmin and iRegularAdmin, I think you can see. Again, see docs page - class could not implement two interfaces that specified a method with the same name, since it would cause ambiguity.